# CMake: Get root project name

Tags: c, cmake, project

Suppose I have following C project structure:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   ├── header.h
├── README.md 
├── src
│   └── src.c
└── test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── test.c
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` in the root directory contains a project called `cproj`

```
PROJECT(cproj C)
```

Also in `test/CMakeLists.txt`, I have another project

```
PROJECT(test C)
```

The question is how can I assess the project name `cproj` in the `CMakeLists.txt` in `test` directory?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to access the root project name? Normally I just call the root project "xproject" and the tests project will be simply "xproject-test"

Comment: @ThuYeinTun Because I may want to change the name in the future, and I prefer changing it only once while taking effect across the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I gather your use case correctly, you should probably do as follows:

1. `test` is quite likely not a standalone sub-project. It should not have a `project` directive. If you remove it, it will now be under the `cproj` project.
2. Now you looking for the project name you've set in the root, it should be available via the [`CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME.html#cmake-project-name) variable.

Comment: According to the document, it says `the name of the current project.`. But I have another project in `test/CMakeLists.txt`. So this won't work, will it?

Comment: @tjysdsg - Why would you define another project in `test`? Is it not the test directory of `cproj`? It's not standalone, is it?

Comment: I made test standalone, I just realized that's a stupid move

Comment: Now, CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME is the name of the top level `project`, not the most recent: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/variable/CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME.html#variable:CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME